# How to project the result of an aggregate query result with Panache and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, quarkus-panache

Consider this method:

```
public static Uni<List<ReactivePanacheMongoEntityBase>> getAverage(String productId) {
    List<Bson> pipeline = new ArrayList<>();
    Bson match = Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("productId", new ObjectId(productId)));
    Bson group = Aggregates.group("$productId", new BsonField("Average", new Document("$avg", "$score")));
    pipeline.add(match);
    pipeline.add(group);
    return Rating.mongoCollection().aggregate(pipeline).collect().asList();
}
```

**How to I project the results to a custom class?** The project() only exists in conjunction with find()